# using a library

Tags: ros, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am a newbie to ROS (and to C++ as well). I need to use some fuctions and classes from a library "itpp-4.2" .Now i have successfully installed the library locally (as i dont have sudo rights) in a folder /home/abc/itpp-4.2 . I want to use these function in a ros node in a ros package. so how can i do that. what files do i need to modify.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30230/using-a-library/) by [kernelfrank](https://answers.ros.org/users/2033/kernelfrank/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On your CMakeList.txt in your ros pkg you need to add something like this:

```
rosbuild_add_executable(your_node src/your_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(your_node itpp-4.2)
```

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) with karma: 591 on 2012-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-03-22**:
Since that library isn't going to be in the standard folders to look in when linking, you'll also need to add that to the linker search path as well as the headers to the include paths. Look at the CMake docs, specifically the link_directories and include_directories commands .

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on what you want to achieve, you don't need to do anything ROS specific.
You could just use normal cmake commands you would use for any other library.

This would be OK, if the library can usually be installed as a system library. In that case it is could practice to setup rosdep so the library can be found by ROS.

On the other hand, if the library can't easily be installed in general, you would need to wrap it into a ROS package.

Look here: [Third Party Libraries](http://www.ros.org/wiki/UsingThirdPartyLibraries)

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-03-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jason](https://answers.ros.org/users/29292/jason/) on 2017-02-08**:
Hi I browsed the rosdep, but it confused me. Could you explain more to me to write a ros node with installed library?